# Is there a way to refactor this async function to point free?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have this function:

```
const getData = async player => {
    const [profile, repos] = await Promise.all([
        getProfile(player),
        getRepos(player)
    ])
    return {
        profile,
        repos
    }
}
```

I might not need to change it but I'm just curious whether it's possible to make it point free with Ramda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have already conveys the intent clearly and refactoring to point-free will likely muddy things.

That said, an example of what this could look like:

```js
const getProfile = player => Promise.resolve('player-' + player)
const getRepos = player => Promise.resolve('repo-' + player)

const fn = R.pipeP(
  R.pipe(R.juxt([getProfile, getRepos]), Promise.all.bind(Promise)),
  R.zipObj(['profile', 'repos'])
)

fn('foo').then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This makes use of [`R.juxt`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt) to create a function that passes it's argument to each function in the provided array of Promise-producing functions and [`R.pipeP`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeP) to compose [`R.zipObj`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) with the resulting Promise.